# How to refresh a dictionary with random values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, dictionary

I'm working on a genetic algorithm based on tournament selection, and need to run several populations at once. My problem is that I have a dictionary with random values for the individuals, but when I make a loop checking for these values they are the same.

Is there any way to refresh a dictionary so the random values are changed?

My dictionary:

```
individuals = {

    'a': [random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4)],
    'b': [random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4)],
    'c': [random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4)],
    'd': [random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4)],
    'e': [random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4)],
    'f': [random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4)],
    'g': [random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4)],
    'h': [random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4)],
    'i': [random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4)]
}
```

My loop:

```
def run_generation():
    global random_individuals, fitness_scores
    for k in range(tournamentSize):
        randchoice = random.sample(list(individuals), 1)[0] #update individual list so values are different??!
        randchoice = individuals.get(randchoice)
        random_individuals.append(randchoice)
```

Currently, I'm just redefining the dictionary each time I form a new population (just copy-pasting the dictionary), but that seems uneconomical and would be sluggish once the population grows larger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may easily generate your dictionary on the fly using simple list comprehensions:

```
individuals = { i : [random.randint(-4,4) for _ in range(6)] for i in 'abcdefghi' }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can turn it into a function so everytime it's called, it returns a new dict of randomized numbers.

```
def individuals():
    return { 
        'a': [random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4)], 
        'b': [random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4)], 
        'c': [random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4)], 
        'd': [random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4)], 
        'e': [random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4)], 
        'f': [random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4)], 
        'g': [random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4)], 
        'h': [random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4)], 
        'i': [random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4),random.randint(-4,4)] }
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - however, I'm getting TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable